# How do i change my current web view in my spring mvc controller when i send data from my ajax to the controller?

Tags: javascript, ajax, spring, jsp, spring-mvc

So i'm currently able to send my json data from my ajax successfully to my controller method and map it successfully. Problem is when the mapping is done and a couple other processes are performed in the controller method i return my jsp. But for some reason my web view doesn't change to the new page i want it to switch to.

Here's my ajax

```
function returnData(changedFields){
    console.log("Made it into function");
    $.ajax({
        url:'addfields',
        type:'POST',
        contentType:'application/json',
        data:changedFields,     

        success: function(response){

            console.log("Made it into ajax success");
        }

    });

}
```

Here's my spring MVC controller Method

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "addfields")
public @ResponseBody ModelAndView getFieldsJson(@RequestBody ContractFields contractFields)
        throws Exception {

    System.out.println("Worked");

    return new ModelAndView("search");
}
```

So right now what i'm trying to do is wipe the current view and show a new view.

Here's what the flow of my program looks like

search.jsp--->fields.jsp---->search.jsp(i want to return back to this jsp)

Problem is when i click f12  and view the network tab i can see that the view is  being returned under in the preview tap but the webpage isn't changing.

Comment: If that's what you want just do a regular form `POST` instead of submitting via AJAX.  What you're doing now, fields.jsp has javascript running in the page; that submits a post via ajax and receives the results as `response` in your `success` callback function.  Nothing is telling the _browser_ to load a new page.  You could have that function set `window.location=somewherenew` after you check the response, but if all you allways want is search-->fields-->search just do a non-ajax plain submit.

Comment: okay and i will still be able to send over my json data to my controller if i do a non-ajax plain submit. 
I did try doing a window.localtion = '/search' but it actually sends me to a url that does not exist.
Meaning instead of my full path localhost/...../....../search it takes me to localhost/search.
sorry this is my first time working with spring mvc so mos of my work is learning on the fly.